# How to handle **kwargs when passing them DIRECTLY to multiprocessing's Pool?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I would like to pass `kwargs` to a `multiprocessing` `Pool`. Passing `kwargs` to the function works, but using multiprocessing does not.

How is it possible to use `kwargs` in this context?

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

abc = [13, 15]
xyz = [2,3,5]

parameterGridDic = [{
    'abc': abc,
    'xyz': xyz
}]

def myFunc(**kwargs):
    return kwargs['xyz'], kwargs['abc']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()

    parameterGrid = ParameterGrid(parameterGridDic)
    parameterGridList = list(parameterGrid)

    for parameterGridEntry in parameterGridList:
        myResult = myFunc(**parameterGridEntry)
        print("myResult:", myResult)


    pool = Pool(cpu_count())
    myResult2 = pool.map(myFunc,**parameterGridList)

    print("myResult2:", myResult2)
```

This produces the following output:

```
myResult: (2, 13)
myResult: (3, 13)
myResult: (5, 13)
myResult: (2, 15)
myResult: (3, 15)
myResult: (5, 15)

...

    myResult2 = pool.map(myFunc,**parameterGridList)
TypeError: map() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list
```

Comment: You pass `parameterGridList`, which is likely a list, using `**` as if it were a `dict`. Please read carefully [what `pool.map` actually expects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map). You likely need to just drop the `**`.

Comment: @9000 Thanks for your comment. If I try this, the following error is raised at that statement: `TypeError: myFunc() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: Indeed. `myFunc` takes only kwargs. But `pool.map` takes a function and a _list_ of things to give each parallel function invocation. Each element of that list will be given to an invocation of `myFunc`, as a positional parameter. But `myFunc` does not take positional parameters. It should start accepting them by dropping the `**` in its parameter list. Then you'd pass a list of dicts to `pool.map`, each invocation of `myFunc` will receive a dict, and will proceed without further changes. I think there's no way to pass `**kwargs` to a function run by `.map`.